# Data binding for two textbox

Tags: c#, wpf

I have 2 textbox, each in a different listview. First textbox is supposed to show data from a xml file. So when i click on the textbox, the data in the first textbox will show on the second textbox. I did this by  doing a very big round about, getting the specific object when i click it and append to another listview. Is there a shorter way to do this through binding by element name in the xaml? My elementName in textbox1 will be the name for textbox2. I try doing it, but I am not sure what my path should be?

Sorry for not including my xaml.

```
<Window x:Class="GridViewTest.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
     xmlns:diag="clr-namespace:System.Diagnostics;assembly=WindowsBase"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:GridViewTest"
    Title="MainWindow" mc:Ignorable="d" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" d:DesignHeight="541" d:DesignWidth="858" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight">
<Window.Resources>
    <local:PacketList x:Key="PacketList"/>
    <local:BindableSelectionTextBox x:Key="BindableSelectionTextBox"/>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid Height="500" Width="798">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="142*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="145*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="234*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="233*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding}" x:Name="lvItems" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="True">
                <GridViewColumn Header="Header" Width="200">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid>
                                <TextBox Name ="A" Tag="Header" Text="{Binding SelectedText, Path=headerObj.headervalue}" PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp="Handle_Click"
                                         IsReadOnly="True" BorderThickness="0" >
                                </TextBox>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
    <ListView Margin="0,245,0,8" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.RowSpan="2" >
        <TextBox  Name="headText" Text="{Binding SelectedText,ElementName=A}"/>
    </ListView>    
</Grid>
```

Comment: Are the two textboxes in the same container/user control/window?

Comment: Yes they are in the same container/user control/window

Comment: Posted. My textBox A is binding to a observable collection of class Packet. My class Packet consists of a header class which contains a string.

So what I wanted to achieve is that when i click on TextBox A, whatever data inside will appear in textbox headText, and when i select the text in headText, the corresponding part in A will be selected as well. 

i got this bindable textbox class which i am using, but I am not sure how to bind it to my textbox A or textbox headText.

Comment: This is a duplicate post by you. Why didnt you update your previous post? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7873438/selected-text-in-textbox

Comment: @AngelWPF oh this is about the binding part. The previous post is about the selected text. But I still cant get the selected text to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly let us have some education on `NameScoping` in WPF. In WPF any Bindings within `Templates` are scoped to that `Template` only. Also any element named within a template wont be available for `Binding.ElementName` reference outside the template.

**So in your case TextBox `A` cannot be referred by TextBox `headText` as textbox `A` is name-scoped under `GridViewColumn.CellTemplate`.**

Also why is `headText` textbox under a `ListView`? `ItemsControls` like `ListBox`, `ListView`, `DataGrid` should not be used as panels or containers to host single elements. Their intention is to show multiple items. Use `Panel`s or `ContentControl` instead.

```
   <Grid Margin="0,245,0,8" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.RowSpan="2" >
       <TextBox  Name="headText" Text="{Binding SelectedText,ElementName=A}"/>
   </Grid>
```

OR

```
   <ContentControl Margin="0,245,0,8" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.RowSpan="2" >
       <TextBox  Name="headText" Text="{Binding SelectedText,ElementName=A}"/>
   </ContentControl>
```

Now to synchronize selection between two textboxes use the following trick...

**XAML**

```
    <TextBox Name="SelectionSource"
             Tag="{Binding ElementName=SelectionTarget}"
             SelectionChanged="SelectionSource_SelectionChanged" />
    <TextBox Name="SelectionTarget"
             Text="{Binding SelectedText, ElementName=SelectionSource,
                            Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}" />
```

**Code Behind ...**

```
    private void SelectionSource_SelectionChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var targetTextBox = ((TextBox) sender).Tag as TextBox;
        if (targetTextBox != null)
        {
            var bndExp
                = BindingOperations.GetBindingExpression(
                    targetTextBox, TextBox.TextProperty);

            if (bndExp != null)
            {
                bndExp.UpdateTarget();
            }
        }
    }
```

If you are using MVVM then handle this `SelectionSource_SelectionChanged` event in attached behavior.

**EDIT 2:**

Now in case if one text box is part of ListBox template and other is outside the template then use content control hack...

**XAML:**

```
   <Window.Resources>      
    <TextBox x:Key="SelectionTarget"
             Text="{Binding Tag.SelectedText,
                            RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},
                            Mode=TwoWay,
                            UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}" />
  </Window.Resources>

  <StackPanel>
     <ListBox>
        <ListBox.ItemsSource>
            <x:Array Type="{x:Type System:String}">
                <System:String>Test String 1</System:String>
                <System:String>Test String 2</System:String>
                <System:String>Test String 3</System:String>
            </x:Array>
        </ListBox.ItemsSource>
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBox Name="SelectionSource"
                         Text="{Binding Path=., Mode=TwoWay}" 
                         Tag="{StaticResource SelectionTarget}"
                         SelectionChanged="SelectionSource_SelectionChanged" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>

    <ContentControl Content="{StaticResource SelectionTarget}">           
    </ContentControl>

</StackPanel>
```

**Code Behind**

```
    private void SelectionSource_SelectionChanged(
       object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var targetTextBox
             = ((TextBox) sender).Tag as TextBox;
        if (targetTextBox != null)
        {
            targetTextBox.Tag = (TextBox) sender;

            var bndExp
                = BindingOperations.GetBindingExpression(
                    targetTextBox, TextBox.TextProperty);

            if (bndExp != null)
            {
                bndExp.UpdateTarget();
            }
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: ohhhh i did not know about the binding between elements between 2 template. thats a very good example!. Thanks so much!!!!

Comment: in this case, is there any way I can implement one of the textbox as the textbox for the cells of a table and the other textbox as it is?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what's going on with "SelectedText" you are trying to bind to, but if all you are trying to do is display the "lvItems" SelectedItem text in your "headText" TextBox the following should work

```
<TextBox Name="headText" Text="{Binding ElementName=lvItems, Path=SelectedItem.headerObj.headervalue}" />
```

You'll need to change your TextBox "A" binding as well.

```
<TextBox Name ="A" Tag="Header" Text="{Binding headerObj.headervalue}" IsReadOnly="True" BorderThickness="0" >
</TextBox>
```

Assuming that headerObj is a property of the Packet class, and headervalue is a property of that, and headervalue is the value you wish to bind to.

The text in "headText" will update when the SelectedItem is changed (not when the TextBox is clicked).