# Selected text lost focus in one textbox

Tags: c#, wpf

I have two textbox A and B which have the same text. So when i select some text in A, same text in B will be selected. I can do this but the highlight will disapppear in A instead when the text in B is highlighted. How do I make it such that in both textboxes, the text will be highlighted?

Comment: Didnt your own post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7873438/selected-text-in-textbox/7873510#7873510 has answer to this question already?

Comment: Oh i did not try that in the end. I use another way to make the effect. But because when I select some text in A and release my mouse, the text in B is selected but the text in A will not be selected on mouse up

Comment: Can you share you **another way** coz the attached behavior approach to convert normal CLR properties to dependency properties should have worked in your case.

Comment: @AngelWPF oh now i am using a datagrid to present my textbox A1,A2 and so on. so when i click on textbox A, there will be a textbox B showing. so i keep a index for each of the object inside a textbox so that i know which column to look at, then from there I do the select on textbox A.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think this is an easy thing to do. By default, only 1 'thing' at the time can be highlighted. This is logical because what if we highlight and press CTRL + C. If there are 2 things highlighted (selected), we have some weird/unpredictable functionality going on.

You can however make your own custom TextBox control inherited from the defacto TextBox in which you can bind multiple textboxes together and let them reflect their highlights.

Comment: Making your own custom TextBox is definitely not the way to go. The correct way is to retemplate the TextBox.

Answer (score 1):

I think for this requierement you have to program a custom control based on the textbox control. Then you can override the action which focus and highlight the textbox. Then this custom control only highlight and dont set the focus at the second textbox.

Its only an idea i dont know how it works in practice...